# setAttribute перенос строки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать перенос строки в setAttribute? \r\n не сработали и \n тоже и это тоже

bt11.setAttribute("data-tooltip","Количество"+"\r\n"+"очков ");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть речь про тултипы - вот такой вариант, найдено [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047694/add-line-break-to-after-or-before-pseudo-element-content)

```js
var x = "hello";
var y = "world";

document.querySelector("span").setAttribute("data-tooltip", x+"  "+y);
```

```css
[data-tooltip]:before {
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

[data-tooltip]:before {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 22px;
  margin-left: 22px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-tooltip) '\A' attr(data-tooltip);
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

[data-tooltip]:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<span class="asd">123</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x = "hello";
var y = "world";

document.querySelector("span").setAttribute("data-tooltip", x+"\n"+y);
```

```html
<span class="asd">123</span>
```

```js
document.querySelector("span").setAttribute("data-tooltip", "Количество \n Очков");
```

```html
<span class="asd">123</span>
```